# Restoring the database file without knowing the password

Tags: mysql

I have to restore a database somenam.sql file i dont know the password for phpMyAdmin login
can it be done through command line?

i am working on Ubuntu system with MySql database system.

Comment: Do you have database credentials? Do you manage the server?

Comment: I dont manage the server. I have downloaded one database on my system

Answer (score 2):

You always need *some* password to access mySQL. If necessary, a system administrator can [reset the root password](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/resetting-permissions.html).